# react.js redirect inside function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I was trying to implement a conditional redirecting.

So inside a function I used this :

```
if(request.responseText==="true"){
     window.location.href = '/home';
}
...
```

But as I'm using react.js I'm trying to implement `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`.

So I tried this code :

```
if(request.responseText==="true"){
      <Router>
          <Redirect to={"/home"}/>
      </Router>
} 
...
```

But now it's not even compiling, it gives me error :

**Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component should be wrapped in **withRouter**, see [React Router - withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter), then your component now has **history** in the props. In your example use it like so:

```
if(request.responseText==="true"){
    this.props.history.push('/home')
}
```

Hope this helps! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to wrap it with `Router`, you can just have this,

```
if(request.responseText==="true"){
   return <Redirect to="/home" />
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation it should be

```
 <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
```

Note that the curly braces are removed.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md